# Python dictionary get the value with the least 'attribute' value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in python. In my dictionary, I hold one type of  key and one type of value. My keys in dictionary are a class that I defined. And my values are another class that I defined. In my value part the class is a node.

```
class key(object):
    def __init__(self,k)
        self.k = k
# ...
```

In Node class I have something like

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
# ...
```

How can I get the node with the least x value from the dictionary. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: As in `min(d.values(), key=operator.attrgetter('x'))`? Why do the keys matter in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pythonic and fast

```
import operator

find_min = min(your_dict.values(), key=operator.attrgetter('x'))
```

Comment: `min()` takes a `key=` kwarg, that simplifies matters quite a lot.

Comment: @dhke So this answer is not useful?

Comment: Then I would have downvoted it. I just suggested an improvement.

Comment: @dhke just looked at the documentation: yes that would be better, agreed

Comment: Maybe you should delete the first answer. But the second one is correct and faster. Thanks by the way

Comment: Additional item to make it truly Pythonic, don't use a lambda.  Instead, use `operator.attrgetter` a la: `min(your_dict.values(), key=attrgetter('x'))` — no need to execute the bytecode stack operations for attribute lookup in a tight loop.